# Error: Unknown column 'status' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT item_number, item_name, description, status, active_date, inactive_date, creation_date, creation_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by, 
(CASE WHEN inactive_date IS NULL THEN 
    CASE WHEN active_date <= curdate() THEN 'ACTIVE' ELSE 'FUTURE ACTIVE' END
 ELSE  
     CASE WHEN active_date = inactive_date THEN 'INACTIVE'
          WHEN active_date <= curdate() AND inactive_date > curdate() THEN 'ACTIVE'
          WHEN active_date >  curdate() AND inactive_date > curdate() THEN 'FUTURE ACTIVE' 
     ELSE 'INACTIVE' END 
 END) as status
```

Please help me. I am new with mysql.

Comment: Does your table have a column called `status`?  If not, then remove it from the select list.  If it does have it, then change the alias name of the case statement to something else.

Comment: you have no `from`

Comment: @Drew .... or table name, etc.  I'm pretty sure the error is face value.

Comment: well there are 2 status's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your SELECT, you have `status` included:

```
SELECT item_number, item_name, description, status
```

Since you define `status` with `AS` as a new column, I suspect that your table does not have a `status` column itself. Remove `status` and turn the line to

```
SELECT item_number, item_name, description, active_date, inactive_date, creation_date, creation_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by,
```

Answer (score 0):

remove status from the `select` it is not needed if it is a result of `case`

```
SELECT item_number, item_name, description, active_date, inactive_date, creation_date, creation_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by, 
(CASE WHEN inactive_date IS NULL THEN 
    CASE WHEN active_date <= curdate() THEN 'ACTIVE' ELSE 'FUTURE ACTIVE' END
 ELSE  
     CASE WHEN active_date = inactive_date THEN 'INACTIVE'
          WHEN active_date <= curdate() AND inactive_date > curdate() THEN 'ACTIVE'
          WHEN active_date >  curdate() AND inactive_date > curdate() THEN 'FUTURE ACTIVE' 
     ELSE 'INACTIVE' END 
 END) as Status
```

Also `from` class is missing.

Comment: thanks @jens it works... sorry for this silly mistake.... obviously there is no STATUS column in my table..... and now "Error: Unknown column 'status' in 'where clause'" when i do this.... FROM item_master WHERE status = '".$_POST['status']."'";.... In oracle this should work....

Comment: @DienyAkmal No you can not access am an alias in where Statement. you have to use having clause instead